# How to trigger a function when page is fully loaded on Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm currently using jQuery to execute a function but seems it's only working on the desktop but not on the mobile device, I have added jQuery Mobile to my WP theme.

I want to execute this function only when a page is fully loaded on mobile device

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
 jQuery('.jp-play').trigger('click');
 //jQuery('.jp-pause').click();
 jQuery('.jp-pause').hide();

  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On classic jQuery you generally use the `.ready()` function to trigger events when the page has been loaded, but in jQuery Mobile it's recommended to use the `pageinit` event:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery(document).ready(callback)` to trigger the `callback` function when the page is fully loaded. Should work on both desktop and mobile.

Example script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(()=>{
    console.log("I'm ready!");
});
```

If that doesn't work you can try the special `jquery-mobile` event `mobileinit`:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
  console.log("I'm ready!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    jQuery('.jp-play').trigger('click');
    //jQuery('.jp-pause').click();
    jQuery('.jp-pause').hide();
});
```